# Need to copy log files daily from remote to local server Linux

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I want to run a bash cron job in my local server to copy archive log files from a remote server that has been generated on that same day. On the first go, I have copied all the previous files but now I need to copy only newly generated log files from remote to local computer?

I have tried using SCP command but couldn't able to manage datestamp to copy new files
Any help?

Comment: just to add, I just want new files to copy not the old files to overwrite as the bandwidth is limited and logs files are in GBs

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. If you show us the code you wrote, we can hopefully tell you what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a shell script I run as a cron job to copy a database dump from a server (I've changed the names of the server and the dump):

```
#!/bin/bash
rsync -aue ssh phma@server.example.com:/home/phma/dump.*.gz /home/phma/dback/
```

The server has a cron job that dumps the database each night; the * in the filename corresponds to a digit which indicates the day of the week.

Rsync copies the parts that changed in a file, so if you have a log file that grew overnight, it will copy the new part and not bother pulling the part it already has from the original. If the remote server is rotating logs, you may have to rotate logs on the local server, so that it doesn't copy the entirety of remote:log.3 because it's different from local:log.3 when it's the same as local:log.2.